# Autosave with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autosave

I am trying to make an autosave script with jQuery, MySQL and PHP, but for some reason I can't get it to work.

My jQuery script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.post("autosave-ks.php", function (data) {
            $("[name='hb']").val(data.hb);
            $("[name='lb']").val(data.lb);
        }, "json");
        setInterval(function () {
            $.post("autosave-ks.php", $("betingelser").serialize());
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

And my autosave-ks.php

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    $texthandelsbetingelser = nl2br($_POST['hb']);
    mysqli_query($mysql_link, "UPDATE dagenshug_kundeservice SET text='$texthandelsbetingelser' WHERE id = '1'");
    $textleveringbetingelser = nl2br($_POST['lb']);
    mysqli_query($mysql_link, "UPDATE dagenshug_kundeservice SET text='$textleveringbetingelser' WHERE id = '2'");
}
```

My form

```
<form action="index.php?site=kundeservice&update=1" method="post" name="betingelser">
<textarea type=\"text\" rows=\"40\" cols=\"167\" name=\"hb\">".str_replace('<br />', '', $row['text'])."</textarea>"
<textarea type=\"text\" rows=\"40\" cols=\"167\" name=\"lb\">".str_replace('<br />', '', $row['text'])."</textarea>"
</form>
```

Any one look into it ? - i just not save

Comment: Is JavaScript showing any error? Firefox shows JavaScript errors with Tools | Web Developer | Web Console.

Comment: no errors as far, as i can se

Comment: You may open firefox developer tools and see if any of the post requests are sent or not. That could be a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct selector within your interval:

```
$.post('autosave-ks.php', $('[name="betingelser"]').serialize());
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution is (instead of using `serialize()`)

```
    $(function () {
    $.post("autosave-ks.php", function (data) {
        $("[name='hb']").val(data.hb);
        $("[name='lb']").val(data.lb);
    }, "json");
    setInterval(function () {
        $.post("autosave-ks.php", {hb:$("textarea[name=hb]").val(),lb:$("textarea[name=lb]").val()});
    }, 2000);
});
```